# popen with array of arguments

Tags: c, linux

It seems like [there's no good library function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685039/how-to-portably-use-system-or-popen-but-with-array-of-arguments) I can use for popen with array of arguments instead of single shell-interpreted shell. So I implemented my own one: [c](https://github.com/vi/udpserv/blob/master/popen_arr.c) [h](https://github.com/vi/udpserv/blob/master/popen_arr.h).

**popen_arr.h**

```
#pragma once

struct FILE;

// Implemented by Vitaly _Vi Shukela in 2013, License=MIT

/**
* Fork and exec the program, enabling stdio access to stdin and stdout of the program
* You may close opened streams with fclose.
* Note: the procedure does no signal handling except of signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
* You should waitpid for the returned PID to collect the zombie or use signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
*
* @arg in stdin of the program, to be written to. If NULL then not redirected
* @arg out stdout of the program, to be read from. If NULL then not redirected
* @arg program full path of the program, without reference to $PATH
* @arg argv NULL terminated array of strings, program arguments (includiong program name)
* @arg envp NULL terminated array of environment variables, NULL => preserve environment
* @return PID of the program or -1 if failed
*/
int popen2_arr (FILE** in, FILE** out, const char* program, const char* const argv[], const char* const envp[]);

/** like popen2_arr, but uses execvp/execvpe instead of execve/execv, so looks up $PATH */
int popen2_arr_p(FILE** in, FILE** out, const char* program, const char* const argv[], const char* const envp[]);

/**
* Simplified interface to popen2_arr.
* You may close the returned stream with fclose.
* Note: the procedure does no signal handling except of signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
* You should wait(2) after closing the descriptor to collect zombie process or use signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)
*
* @arg program program name, can rely on $PATH
* @arg argv program arguments, NULL-terminated const char* array
* @arg pipe_into_program 1 to be like popen(...,"w"), 0 to be like popen(...,"r")
* @return FILE* instance or NULL if error
*/
FILE* popen_arr(const char* program, const char* const argv[], int pipe_into_program);
```

**popen_arr.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE // execvpe 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "popen_arr.h"


// Implemented by Vitaly _Vi Shukela in 2013, License=MIT

static int popen2_impl(FILE** in, FILE** out,  const char* program, const char* const argv[], const char* const envp[], int lookup_path) {

    int child_stdout = -1;
    int child_stdin = -1;

    int to_be_written = -1;
    int to_be_read = -1;

    if(in) {
        int p[2]={-1,-1}; 
        int ret = pipe(p);
        if(ret!=0) { return -1; }
        to_be_written=p[1];
        child_stdin =p[0];
        *in = fdopen(to_be_written, "w");
        if (*in == NULL) {
            close(to_be_written);
            close(child_stdin);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(out) {
        int p[2]={-1,-1};
        int ret = pipe(p);
        if(ret!=0) {
            if (in) {
               close(child_stdin);
               fclose(*in);
               *in = NULL;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        to_be_read   =p[0];
        child_stdout=p[1];
        *out = fdopen(to_be_read, "r");
    }


    int childpid = fork();
    if(!childpid) {
       if(child_stdout!=-1) {
           close(to_be_read);
           dup2(child_stdout, 1);
           close(child_stdout);
       }
       if(child_stdin!=-1) {
           close(to_be_written);
           dup2(child_stdin, 0);
           close(child_stdin);
       }
       if (lookup_path) {
           if (envp) {
               execvpe(program, (char**)argv, (char**)envp);
           } else {
               execvp (program, (char**)argv);
           }
       } else {
           if (envp) {
               execve(program, (char**)argv, (char**)envp);
           } else {
               execv (program, (char**)argv);
           }
       }
       _exit(ENOSYS);
    }

    if(child_stdout!=-1) {
        close(child_stdout);
    }
    if(child_stdin!=-1) {
        close(child_stdin);
    }

    return childpid;
}


int popen2_arr  (FILE** in, FILE** out,  const char* program, const char* const argv[], const char* const envp[])
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    return popen2_impl(in, out, program, argv, envp, 0);
}
int popen2_arr_p(FILE** in, FILE** out,  const char* program, const char* const argv[], const char* const envp[])
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    return popen2_impl(in, out, program, argv, envp, 1);
}
FILE* popen_arr(const char* program, const char* const argv[], int pipe_into_program) {
    FILE* f = NULL;
    if (pipe_into_program) {
        popen2_arr_p(&f, NULL, program, argv, NULL);
    } else {
        popen2_arr_p(NULL, &f, program, argv, NULL);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Do you have any advice on promoting it from just a project's code snippet into a reusable little library? Is API good? Shall it provide more features (at expence of being complexier) or more simpler (but a bit tricker to use)? Are there obviously bad parts of the code?

Comment: From what I read, you are not asking how to improve it, you are asking how to make it a library.

Comment: I see library code as one requiring higher quality than usual application code. So "making this into a library" implies "making good API, removing hacks". Shall I reformulate the question a bit? I'm not asking how to make it into *.a or *.so or how to create package with it...

Answer (score 2):

The function `popen_arr` would resemble `popen` more closely if it
took a 'mode' parameter in the same way, instead of your `pipe_into_program`:

```
FILE* popen_arr(const char* program,
                const char* const argv[], 
                const char *mode);
```

where `mode` is "r", "w" or "r+".

And `popen` manages bidirectional operation using just one `FILE *` whereas
your `popen2_*` functions take two.

Personally, I would simplify things by omitting the environment parameters.

The bidirectional link you create is perhaps easier to create with
`socketpair`.

`fdopen` failure is caught in the `if(in)` case but not in the `if(out)`
case.

You also need an analogue of `pclose` that closes the pipes and waits for the
child process to exit (using `wait` etc).

You also omit any handling of `SIGCHLD`, which is sent of the death of the child process.

On your formatting, your spacing is inconsistent and there is often
insufficient spacing, eg around operators (=, != etc) and after keywords (eg
after `if`).

Comment: BTW am I expected on codereview.SE to edit the question according to the recommendations or leave it as is?

Comment: No don't edit the code in the original question (answers refer to that code).

Comment: How we should handle SIGCHLD? Store old handler, override, handle then restore old handler? Does usual popen deal with SIGCHLD?